# Inherit from dataclass without specifying everything in subclass' __init__?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'm building a hierarchy of `dataclasses.dataclass` (Python 3.10).

E.g.

```py
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    a: int

@dataclasses.dataclass
class B(A):
    b: int
```

I now have a bunch of `A`s, which I want to additionally specify as `B` without adding all of `A`'s properties to the constructor. Something like this:

```
a = A(1)

b = B(a, 1)
```

I know I could use `dataclasses.asdict`

```py
b = B(**dataclasses.asdict(a), b=1)
```

Is this an acceptable solution in the sense of best practice? It looks a bit inefficient and less readable than it could be.

I tried overwriting the `B.__init__` (and `B.__new__`) but this seems like too much code is needed. And with overwriting the `__init__`, it's not possible to make the dataclass `frozen`.

Comment: `B` is also `A`, just do `b = B(1, 2)` and see what `isinstance(b, A)` returns.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to retype all the arguments for `A` again.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a `classmethod` on `B` to make your approach more ergonomic.

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class B(A):
    b: int
    
    @classmethod
    def from_A(cls, a, **kwargs):        
        return cls(**dataclasses.asdict(a), **kwargs)

b = B.from_A(a, b=1)
```